# How do I enable aio on nginx on FreeBSD?

Tags: nginx, freebsd

I want to use asynchronous IO on nginx on FreeBSD. I see lots of documentation on how to configure it or how to compile nginx with it.

However, I already have nginx installed so I need to re-compile nginx with aio enabled. The recompile part is what I don't know how to do.

I'm using the nginx (v0.7.67) port provided with FreeBSD 8.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What version of nginx do you use?

Comment: The version of nginx I am using is 0.7.67

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to add AIO support to your FreeBSD. You can use two ways for do this. 
1) Add "options VFS_AIO"  and rebuild kernel.
2) Loaded AIO dynamically via loadable kernel module: kldload aio

Add this lines to config after that:

```
location /video/ {
    sendfile       off;
    aio            on;
    output_buffers 1 64k;
}
```

You can use sendfile for AIO:

```
location /video/ {
    sendfile       on;
    tcp_nopush     on;
    aio            sendfile;
}
```

Both variants will work.

Comment: You can load AIO dynamically on boot by adding aio_load="YES" to /boot/loader.conf, easier than recompiling. You may also need to rebuild the nginx port with the "Enable file aio" option checked.

Comment: I thought AIO was enabled on FreeBSD 8 by default. I guess I was wrong. How can I check if AIO is enabled already or not on the kernel?

Comment: I do need to rebuild the nginx port with the "Enable file aio" option checked. How do I do this? (This is my original question)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to enable nginx file aio support on FreeBSD is to install nginx via the ports tree and just select the FILE_AIO option in the dialog.

```
portsnap fetch extract
cd /usr/ports/www/nginx
make install clean
```

But if you want to compile it yourself, download the source, extract it and then:

```
./configure --with-file-aio
make install
```

(You need to run both *portsnap* and *make install* as root!)